# Validating Input fields relating to custom tabs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, tabs

Am working on an application which has some custom built tabs. When the user
clicks on each tab, input fields relating to the tab are displayed automatically.
When the user changes by clicking on another tab, the input fields of the previous tab are hidden
and those of the clicked tab are displayed automatically. This logic works fine.

All the input fields of all the tabs share a common submit button since I need to capture 
the data entered and submit to the backend. The problem arises during frontend validation, I need to
validate the input fields of the specific tab that has opened before the user submits the form.
On all the closed tabs no validation should happen.

**Markup**

```
//Tabs to be clicked by user
<ul>
    <li class="columns">
        <div>
            <label"><span>Just Me or My Spouse</span></label>
        </div>   
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <div>
            <label"><span>Couple</span></label>
        </div>   
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <div>
            <label"><span>My Family</span></label>
        </div>   
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Fields to show conditionally depending on clicked tab**

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="travellerDetail" novalidate>

        <!-- JUST ME OR SPOUSE TAB FIELD-->
        <hr class="row travellerAge" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row travellerAge" style="display: none;">
            <div>
                <h1>Age of the Traveller</h1>
                <p>Select your Age from the datepicker below?</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="justMeDob" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" value="" required> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--END-->

        <!-- COUPLE AGE TAB FIELDS-->
        <hr class="row coupleAge" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row coupleAge" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
                    <h1>Husband Age</h1>
                    <p>Select Husband age from the datepicker below?</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="coupleHusbandAge" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" value="" required>  
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row coupleAge" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
                <h1>Wife Age</h1>
                <p>Select Wife age from the datepicker below?</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="coupleWifeAge" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" value="" required>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--END COUPLE AGE TAB FIELDS-->


        <!-- MY FAMILY TAB FIELDS-->
        <hr class="row mt-5 familyAge" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row familyAge mt-5" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
                    <h1>Spouse Age</h1>
                    <p>Select Spouse age from the datepicker below?</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myFamilySpouseAge" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" value="" required>  
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row familyAge" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
                    <h1>Children</h1>
                    <p>Select Number of Children you are travelling with?</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control otherMenu wide" id="myFamilyChildSelect">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
                        <option value="0"> 0 </option>
                        <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--END MYFAMILY TAB FIELDS-->


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <button> Back </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submitPhase2"> Next </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**My Logic to check tab clicked and display corresponding inputs conditionally**

```
let traveller = false;
let value = "";
$(".columns").click(function () {
    if (!traveller) {
        //Check the text that was clicked
        var person = $(this).text();
        if(person.trim() == "Just Me or My Spouse"){
            //Show Individual input and hide others
            $('.travellerAge').fadeIn(1000);
            $('.coupleAge').css('display' , 'none');
            $('.familyAge').css('display' , 'none');
            value = 'justMeOrSpouse';
        }
        if(person.trim() == "Couple"){
            //Show Couple inputs and hide others
            $('.coupleAge').fadeIn(1000);
            $('.travellerAge').css('display', 'none');
            $('.familyAge').css('display' , 'none');
            value = 'couple';
        }
        if(person.trim() == "Family"){
            //Show Family inputs and hide others
            $('.familyAge').fadeIn(1000);
            $('.travellerAge').css('display', 'none');
            $('.coupleAge').css('display' , 'none');
            value = 'myFamily';
        }
        else{
            $('.travellerAge').css('display', 'none');
            $('.coupleAge').css('display' , 'none');
            $('.familyAge').css('display' , 'none');
        }
    }
});
```

**Submit Data depending on the value variable in logic above**

```
if(value == "couple"){
    coupleLogic();
}

if(value = "myFamily"){
    myFamilyLogic();
}
//END
```

**Actual function of invoked logic above**

```
function coupleLogic(){
    $("#travellerDetail").submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //perform validation
        $.ajax({
            //Submit via AJAX
        });
    });
}


function  myFamilyLogic(){
    $("#travellerDetail").submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //perform validation
        $.ajax({
            //Submit via AJAX
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all input fields and check whether their style display doesn't equal to none:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for(let i = 0, max = inputs.length; i < max; i++) {
   if(inputs[i].style.display != "none") {
      //do validation
   }
}
```